# Store procedure return all records but expect is one record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

This is my query for creating store procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAccountDetails`(IN `Accountnumber` VARCHAR(50), IN `casshieldId` VARCHAR(50), IN `transactionbefore` DOUBLE, IN `sourceofTransaction` vARCHAR(50))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM account WHERE AccountNumber = Accountnumber AND casShieldId = casshieldId AND transactionBefore = transactionbefore AND sourceOfTransaction = sourceofTransaction;
END
```

When I call the store procedure:

```
call GetAccountDetails("Accountnumber","casshieldId ",transactionbefore,"sourceofTransaction");
```

It returns all records in that account table.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreate your procedure like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAccountDetails`(IN `Accountnumber1` VARCHAR(50), IN `casshieldId1` VARCHAR(50), IN `transactionbefore1` DOUBLE, IN `sourceofTransaction1` vARCHAR(50))
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM account WHERE AccountNumber = Accountnumber1 AND casShieldId = casshieldId1 AND transactionBefore = transactionbefore1 AND sourceOfTransaction = sourceofTransaction1;
    END
```

The difference is only on the procedure variable name because you put the exact same name with the column name make it always stay true no matter what you pass. The DB will think you compare your column name with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Adding simple changes to the above query

```
 BEGIN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM account WHERE AccountNumber = Accountnumber AND casShieldId = casshieldId AND transactionBefore = transactionbefore AND sourceOfTransaction = sourceofTransaction) AS ALIAS ORDER BY ALIAS.AccountNumber LIMIT 1; END
```

Comment: I try this i getting one record but the input value and output value is mismatched.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you want? You are Calling SP with input values to filter it out from Physical table among N records. There may be possibility u may get more than one record as output. To Limit that u can use LIMIT operator at the end.

Comment: I put limit 1 the table first record only returned.I pass different input but output is same.always show first record.

Comment: Please change all the PROCEDURE variable name. Its exactly same with column name. SQL will think you put something like this: 1=1 or 'JOHN' = 'JOHN' thats why the result is mismatch when you limit it 1 and all record came out when you did not limit it because it always stay true no matter what data you pass

Comment: First off how come your initial query return all rows from table? does the where condition satisfies for all records?.

Comment: share sample data for target table and procedure call with sample parameters